# Easy understanding of UNIX and UNIX shell scripting!

Tags: linux, unix

I am beginner to UNIX,UNIX Shell Scripting.

Can you please guide me through any excellent sites for unix(which are easy to understand),some study materials(tutorials),video tutorials.

Please help!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you take a look at the tutorials from ibm: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash.html